# Plugins - Element Criteria Model. Can I return only entries with a updated date in the last 7 days?

Tags: plugin-development, entries, elementcriteriamodel

My plugin function is ignoring the dateUpdated criteria. Any clue as to why? I'm guessing it's syntax, but I cannot find any examples online as to how to format correctly. I can make this work in a template just fine. I'm new to plugins and PHP. Thanks!

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = 'guide';
    $criteria->order = 'postDate desc';
    $criteria->dateUpdated  > '("now"|date_modify("-7 days"))';
    $entries = $criteria->find();

    if ($entries) {
        //Do that thing with my code
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's some other Craft helpers / static variables that you could use, but this technique works. Create a DateTime object without the param set to get the current time, modify it and format it for use in the query like so:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('-7 days');

// Format datetime for use in query
$timezone = new \DateTimeZone(DateTime::UTC);
$date = $date->format(DateTime::MYSQL_DATETIME, $timezone);

$criteria->dateUpdated = '> '.$date;
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks! I wasn't thinking at all in term of the timezone stuff. Very helpful.